# ccnet sourcecontrol: get updates from svn 1 revision at a time

Tags: svn, version-control, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I am designing a Continuous Integration project. In this process I need the ccnet to build after each revision and then do some custom tasks i.e. it should update from svn only 1 revision at a time and then trigger the build process.

Also I have made a custom dos script to update only one revision. But I can return only some numbers or true/false to show that there are no updates, the svn is not accesible or there is some error.

If I set automatically update sourcecontrol to false in the sourcecontrol block and put my script in the tasks section first. Then if there are no updates and it indicates not to build it will return false. But ccnet will interpret it as an error and email build failed to everyone.

Comment: So, you want CCNET to create a build after each time something is checked in?

Comment: yes I want ccnet to get fired and build for each update. It may not be realtime ccnet may fire after 1 hour and get 1 revision at a time and then build the update, do this until no new revisions are left.

Comment: Do you have to have a build for every revision? or can you roll up all revisions every 15-30 seconds?

Comment: Basically I want to have the build for every revision so that I can make some new patches for each revision. Also I have made a script to get only 1 revision update but I want the ccnet to run the script as source control i.e. if my script returns true then it should proceed with tasks else it should not.

Answer (score 2):

Look at using the External source control task in the ccnet config file.

http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/External